-た verb form preceding ものか
A Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar, p. 268:
"mono ka (2) - a phrase indicating that the speaker wants to do s.t. or is wondering what he/she shoould choose."
The examples they  give include:

修士論文の題目をどのように決めたものか(と)迷っています。I am at a loss as to how I should choose my MA thesis topic.


日本語を勉強したいんですが、どの大学を選んだものかと考えているところです。I want to study Japanese, and I'm wondering which university I should choose.


今年の夏は海外旅行をしようと思っていますが、どの国に行ったものかと思案中です。We're thinking of making a trip abroad this coming summer, and we are trying to figure out which country to visit.

The verbs preceding ものか are in the -た form. However the statements are about the future, not about the past. Also, I can't see any obvious sign of perfect/ resultative aspect that would justify the -た form.
I could just learn this form as it is, but I'd be grateful if someone could explain the reason why the -た form is used here, and maybe draw connections to other similar grammar.

I can't explain the grammar, but i would suggest thinking from the perspective of the end point:  when you're holding the master's thesis, when you've learned Japanese, when you've returned from your trip abroad. From that perspective you asking, "how should I have proceeded?" Almost as if you may or may not have made the wrong choice, with a perspective of 20/20 hindsight.  From the future end point, the decision was already made.  Hence past tense.  You're reflecting on the future plans which will be the past of your future self.

Thank you! I heard a similar explanation for したほうがいい once. Also, the link you provided was very useful.
